# How can I make my background image fade in with the same transition as the rest of my webpage using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, opacity, onload, fade

I have next code to make a fade transition but my background image load first and without fading?

```
   body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s;
   }
```

and then:

```
   <body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
```

And the background image loads first than rest.

I expect the background image loads with the same fading time than te rest.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.body.classList.add('loaded');
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('path/to/your-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

body.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.loaded .background-image {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <!-- Rest of your webpage content -->
</body>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. I have acieved my goal with this code:

body{ overflow-x:hidden;
 scrollbar-face-color:#824100;
 background-color: #181716;
 background-image: url('Circul/CIRCULO2.jpg');
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 5s;

}

and 

<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" >

Answer (score 0):

Leave `<body>` as normal (no `opacity` property is necessary). Define `@keyframes` for the different `opacity` values. Add a `position: fixed`/`z-index: 1` to a direct descendant element of `<body>` (in the example below, it's a `<section>`). Assign `animation` property to said element.

**Details are commented in example**

```css
/**
 * Define a simple set of keyframes named "fade"
 * from {a state of visible} to {a hidden state}
 */
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 /* Allows it to be covered edge to edge. */;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/pKPKR1v/wall0.jpg) no-repeat center; 
  background-size: cover;
}

section {
  position: fixed /* Place fixed within the viewport. */;
  z-index: 1 /* Place "over" <body>. */;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  /**
   * Reference @keyframes "fade"
   * Duration lasts for 5 seconds
   * Forwards fill-mode ensures that animation stays at the
   * last keyframe.
   */
  animation: fade 5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```